# Linux tool to determine which clients are using most of our bandwidth?

Tags: linux, network-monitor

We have a Linux router which firewalls incoming traffic, while allowing the 300+ hosts on our local network to make outgoing connections to the Internet.

I suspect that a few "bandwidth hogs" may be consuming far more than their share, and degrading the experience for the other users. I would like to make some measurements on the Linux router to determine if that is true.

I've Googled for bandwidth usage monitoring tools, and found a bunch of tools which can measure bandwidth usage "by IP". But I suspect this means the *destination* IP, not the *source* IP. I don't care about the remote IPs -- I just want to know which IPs (or better yet, MAC addresses) on the local network are consuming the most bandwidth.

Is there a freely available program for Linux which can help?

Comment: What OS on the router? Some router-specific OS or server OS? Also please mention the tools that don't suit your needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**ntop**](http://www.ntop.org/products/ntop/) may give you what you're looking for.

Comment: Indeed, ntop was able to identify the "bandwidth hogs". Thanks for pointing out a great tool.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have a visual, real-time display, you might want to use [EtherApe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EtherApe). Big nodes = big consumers:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[NetHogs](http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/) might work here - I'd start it up in screen, and switch over to total mode

[image]

[Iptraf](http://iptraf.seul.org/) would work here - its interactive mode shows TCP traffic only

[image]

but its logs seem to include this sort of information in detail